# Java binary multiplier of two int/char arrays

Tags: java, arrays, binary, multiplication

currently i am working on a project, that uses Brainpool elliptic curves. For some tests, i need a binary multiplication of two strings. 
The strings look something like that:

```
String a = "00101001";
String b = "11010010";
```

I convert the two stings into char and integer arrays for the binary multiplication but i dont now how to do it. Can someone help me to handle this? i also tried it with BigInteger but it delets my leading zero's.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work. It creates integers out of the binary string, multiplies the values and the converts it back into a string:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("00101001", 2);
int b = Integer.parseInt("11010010", 2);

int x = a*b;

String result = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
```

Does that work for you?